# Connect to local (vpn) linux machine without an IP

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access

I've come to a predicament in the last 5 minutes. I formatted and created a raspberry pi to run some services. This devices is located elsewhere to where I'm currently, and have no physical access.

I configured the device to connect with argo tunnel to cloudflare to expose an interface for me to control some stuff, and set the device to DHCP since I don't care what IP the device will have (I used to connect with IP:Port in the past, but with cloudflare tunnel that's not the case anymore).

I just found out, that the network the device is connected at, does not have a dhcp server. Meaning, I have no way of connecting to the raspberry (well, as far as I know), without it's ip (SSH etc).

Since it doesn't have an IP from DHCP, it's not connected to the internet, thus no tunnel, no services, no nothing.

BUT, I do have access to the local network it's at with VPN.

Is there something I can do to connect to it so I can setup a static IP?

- Maybe connect to it somehow with it's MAC Address?
- Or send to it some "dummy" dhcp package to prompt it to get an IP (although I suspect IT has to ask for one, not send one to it).
- Setup a DHCP Server temporarily with the VPN and hope the device asks for an IP? Does it even do that? I mean, keep asking for one even though it failed some times during boot.

As I said, being that the location is "remote", it's not easy to gain physical access to it. What can I try?

Comment: You cannot connect to a device using a MAC address, the only way, is with an IP address (explicitly you must be able to create a route to that IP address).

Comment: What kind of interface is exposed ?

Comment: If you set up a temporary dhcp server on the same ethernet segment as the Pi it will (after a short while) take an IP.  You can then reconfigure it with a static.

Comment: The device SHOULD have a static IP at 192.168.1.80. When I connect through VPN for example, I'm given the IP 192.168.1.64.